# Why does Find/Replace zRngResult.Find work fine, but RegEx myRegExp.Execute(zRngResult) mess up the range.Start?

Tags: regex, vba

I wish to select and add comments after certain words, e.g. “not”, “never”, “don’t” in sentences in a Word document with VBA. The Find/Replace with wildcards works fine, but “Use wildcards” cannot be selected with “Match case”. The RegEx can “IgnoreCase=True”, but the selection of the word is not reliable when there are more than one comments in a sentence. The Range.start seems to be getting modified in a way that I cannot understand. 
A similar question was asked in June 2010. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f73ca32d-0af9-47cf-81fe-ce93b13ebc4d/regex-selecting-a-match-within-the-document?forum=worddev

Is there a new/different way of solving this problem?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

The code using RegEx follows:

```
Function zRegExCommentor(zPhrase As String, tComment As String) As Long

Dim sTheseSentences As Sentences
Dim rThisSentenceToSearch As Word.Range, rThisSentenceResult As Word.Range
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection

Options.CommentsColor = wdByAuthor    

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    With myRegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .Pattern = zPhrase
    End With

    Set sTheseSentences = ActiveDocument.Sentences

    For Each rThisSentenceToSearch In sTheseSentences
        Set rThisSentenceResult = rThisSentenceToSearch.Duplicate
        rThisSentenceResult.Select
        Do
            DoEvents
            Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(rThisSentenceResult)
            If myMatches.Count > 0 Then
                rThisSentenceResult.Start = rThisSentenceResult.Start + myMatches(0).FirstIndex
                rThisSentenceResult.End = rThisSentenceResult.Start + myMatches(0).Length
                rThisSentenceResult.Select

                Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
                Selection.TypeText Text:=tComment & "{" & zPhrase & "}"

                rThisSentenceResult.Start = rThisSentenceResult.Start + 1  'so as not to find the same phrase again and again
                rThisSentenceResult.End = rThisSentenceToSearch.End
                rThisSentenceResult.Select
            End If    'If myMatches.Count > 0 Then
        Loop While myMatches.Count > 0
    Next    'For Each rThisSentenceToSearch In sTheseSentences
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Relying on Range.Start or Range.End for position in a Word document is not reliable due to how Word stores non-printing information in the text flow. For some kinds of things you can work around it using Range.TextRetrievalMode, but the non-printing characters inserted by Comments aren't affected by these settings.

I must admit I don't understand why Word's built-in Find with wildcards won't work for you - no case matching shouldn't be a problem. For instance, based on the example: "Never has there been, never, NEVER, a total drought.":

```
FindText:="[n,N][e,E][v,V][e,E][r,R]"
```

Will find all instances of n-e-v-e-r regardless of the capitalization. The brackets let you define a range of values, in this case the combination of lower and upper case for each letter in the search term.

The workarounds described in my MSDN post you link to are pretty much all you can if you insist on RegEx:

Using the Office Open XML (or possibly Word 2003 XML) file format will let you use RegEx and standard XML processing tools to find the information, add comment "tags" into the Word XML, close it all up... And when the user sees the document it will all be there.

If you need to be doing this in the Word UI a slightly different approach should work (assuming you're targeting Word 2003 or later): Work through the document on a range-by-range basis (by paragraph, perhaps). Read the XML representation of the text into memory using the Range.WordOpenXML property, perform the RegEx search, add comments as WordOpenXML, then write the WordOpenXML back into the document using the InserXml method, replacing the original range (paragraph). Since you'd be working with the Paragraph object Range.Start won't be a factor.

Comment: In a sentence like "Never has there been, never, NEVER, a total drought." The wildcards will find only the second never because the first and third contain capital letters. With RegEx, I find all three.  A pointer to good example with Range.WordOpenXML will be greatly appreciated. I have spend two days trying to find a working example, but no luck. I have downloaded and installed Open XML, but keep on getting syntax errors with the "using  end  using" statements in the examples.

Comment: See my edited answer for the example. I don't know of links to any examples for exactly this issue and a discussion in Comments would be too extensive. There are definitely issues with doing Find in Open XML due to how it text "runs" can be broken up due to formatting, spelling and other markup. You might want to take a look around in the openxml and openxml-sdk tags here on SO as well as in the Open XML SDK forum on MSDN. If you decide to ask a question on that you need to specify whether this should run within the Word application interface or whether it can run outside Word.

Comment: Thank you for the edited answer. It helps a lot. I did not think of that solution. However, it works only for words that are 1 to 7 letters long. Longer words, e.g.  "accordingly" cause an error "The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is too complex." Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need wildcards? I don't see any mention of why - they certainly aren't needed for the example you've provided. But if you need them then your only recourse will be to be break down the search term into "bite-size" pieces, run multiple Find on separate Ranges (can't use Selection for this) and see if they're contiguous. It really helps when asking a question to provide all relevant information...

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I just wanted to make sure there was no way of dealing with more than 7 sets of square brackets, that I have overlooked. True, this small example does not really need wildcards. I was trying to make one sub that can handle various find situations. Your replies are much appreciated.